# React & Typescript Issue: trigger elements with InsertionObserver using props and manage them in other component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intersection-observer

My component tree is composed of `App.tsx` which render the sub-components, in this case `Navbar.jsx` and `Home.jsx`.

Below is the `App.jsx` code:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [navbarScroll, setNavbarScrool] = useState(Object)
   
  const handleLocationChange = (navbarScroll: boolean) => {
    setNavbarScrool(navbarScroll)
    return navbarScroll
  }

  const AppRoutes = () => {
    let routes = useRoutes([
      { path: "/", element: <Home handleLocationChange={handleLocationChange}/> },
      { path: "component2", element: <></> },
    ]);
    return routes;
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar navbarScroll={navbarScroll} />
      <AppRoutes />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here, instead, the `Home.jsx` code:

```
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import HomeCSS from "../styles/home.module.css"
import mePhoto from "../assets/me.png"
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface AppProps {
  handleLocationChange: (values: any) => boolean;
}
export default function Home(props: AppProps) {
  const {
    ref: containerChange,
    inView: containerChangeIsVisible,
    entry
  } = useInView();
    
  useEffect(() => { 
    props.handleLocationChange(containerChangeIsVisible)
    //returns false at first render as expected
    console.log("Home " + containerChangeIsVisible)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`${ HomeCSS.container} ${containerChangeIsVisible? HomeCSS.container_variation: ''}`}>
        <div className={HomeCSS.container__children}>
          {/* when i scroll on the div the css change (this works)*/}
          <h1 className={`${ HomeCSS.container__h1} ${containerChangeIsVisible? HomeCSS.container__h1_variation: ''}`}>My<br/> Name</h1>
          <p>Computer Science student.</p>
        </div>
        <img src={mePhoto} className={HomeCSS.image_style} />
      </div>

      <div
        ref={containerChange}
        style={{ height: 800, background: "orange" }}
      >
        <p style={{marginTop:20}}>HIII</p>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

And `Navbar.jsx`:

```
import NavbarCSS from "../styles/navbar.module.css"
import acPhoto from "../assets/ac.png"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface NavbarScroolProp{
  navbarScroll:boolean
}
export default function Navbar(props: NavbarScroolProp) {
  const [scrollState, setScrollState] = useState(false)
  const [pVisible, setpVisible] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setpVisible("")
    }, 3000)
    setpVisible("100%")
  }, [])
    
  //returns false also when should be true
  console.log(props.navbarScroll)

  return ( 
    <>
      {/*the props is undefined so the css doesn't change, i need to do this*/}
      <nav className={`${props.navbarScroll?NavbarCSS.nav__variation:NavbarCSS.nav}`}>
        <div className={NavbarCSS.nav_row}>
          <div className={NavbarCSS.nav_row_container}>
            <img src={acPhoto} className={NavbarCSS.image_style} />
            <p
              className={NavbarCSS.p_style}
              style={{ maxWidth: pVisible }}
            >
              My name
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className={NavbarCSS.nav_row_tagcontainer}>
            <Link className={NavbarCSS.nav_row_tag} to="/"> Home</Link>
            <Link className={NavbarCSS.nav_row_tag} to="/"> About</Link>
            <Link className={NavbarCSS.nav_row_tag} to="/"> Contact</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

In my application I want to change the background color whenever the div referring to the `InsertionObserver` ( I use "`useInView`" hook , from :https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer) is displayed. The problem is that the div in question is in the `Home.jsx` component and I need to change the color of the divs in the navbar as well when the div in Home is triggered(or other components in case I need to in the future).

The question is: How can I dynamically trigger DOM elements of other components (to then perform certain operations) using the `InsertionObserver`?

As you can see from the code I tried to create Props, but everything returns undefined and doesn't involve any changes.
I've tried without `useEffect`, without using the `useInView` hook, passing the object instead of the boolean value, but I can't find any solutions to this problem.

I would like to leave the `Navbar.jsx` component where it is now, so that it is visible in all components.